# Inner products with spherical harmonics in quantum mechanics

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hilbert-space, angular-momentum, spherical-harmonics

Let $|l,m\rangle$ be a simultaneous eigenstate of operators $L^2$ and $L_z$ and we want to calculate $\langle l,m|\cos(\theta)|l,m'\rangle$ where $\theta$ is the angle $[0,\pi]$. It is true that in general $$\langle l,m|\cos(\theta)|l,m'\rangle=0 \tag{1}$$ for the same $l$? Why?

Does the fact that equation $(1)$ is valid have anything to do with parity?

Comment: You do understand that $\cos\theta\propto Y^0_1$, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is true in general, and $l$ doesn't have to be the same: the matrix element is zero because $\cos\theta$ doesn't depend on $\phi$, so the azimuthal wavefunction factorizes and we get a factor of $\delta_{m,m'}$.

More explicitly, the spherical harmonics can be written as $Y_{lm} = N_{lm} P_{lm}(\cos\theta) e^{im\phi}$, where $P_{lm}$ are the associated Legendre polynomials and $N_{lm}$ are normalization constants. Inserting this into the integral we get

$$\begin{align}
\langle l, m| \cos\theta |l', m'\rangle &= \int \left(N_{lm} P_{lm}(\cos\theta) e^{-im\phi}\right) \cos\theta \left( N_{l'm'} P_{l'm'}(\cos\theta) e^{im'\phi} \right) \cos\theta\, d\theta\, d\phi \\
&= N_{lm} N_{l'm'} \int P_{lm}(\cos\theta)P_{l'm'}(\cos\theta) \cos^2\theta\, d\theta \int e^{i(m'-m)\phi}\,d\phi
\end{align}$$

and the last integral is proportional to $\delta_{m,m'}$.

Comment: I was searching for another result that is: $\langle lm|cos(\theta)|lm'\rangle=0$ that means: if the two $l$ are equal, whatever $m$ is, the result is zero even if $m=m'$ which seems to me, is not proven by your integral.

Comment: @Salmone It's not really a good idea to edit your question if you want to ask something else. If you have a different question about what happens when $m=m'$, you should either ask another question (and revert this one to what it originally was), or use the edit function to add that to this question instead of replacing it.

Comment: You're right, I've edited the question again.